Can't see parts of a wall when viewed through a glass panel (shower cabin) from a top view angle
I would like to ask for help with an issue I'm having regarding the reflections / refraction of a glass material for Cycles (Blender 4.0.2).
The glass material is assigned to 2 shower cabin glass panels that are 8mm thick. The issue I'm having is that when viewed from a top view angle (perspective camera not orthographic), the glass panels show the reflections of the environment but parts of the walls behind the glass panels are not visible.
In order to fix this, do I simply need to change the IOR value or do I have to add more shaders / mix shaders to the glass material?
Thanks in advance for any tips!
An example of what I mean can be seen in the image below:

This is what the current glass material shader looks like:

This is what the glass material looks like when viewed from a different angle:


If you mean the front glass which reflects the bright wall and the grey floor: well, that's normal for real glass, at low angles reflectivity can get very high so that the glass seems almost opaque.
Here is a real world example, unfortunately I had no glass at hand, only a plastic CD cover - but to show the principle it is good enough:

As you can see, when taking a pictures almost perpendicular to the cover, you can see the floor behind it. When I tilt the cover so that the viewing angle becomes lower and the bright window with the blinds is reflected, the floor is mostly invisible.
Another thing you can see is that it not only depends on the angle, but also on the brightness of what is reflected and what is transmitted through the glass.
The floor is quite dark, the window is very bright. But even in the left picture, the reflection of my dark phone is more transparent then the part of my hand which is lit up, even though angle is almost the same between those areas.
So there are three main factors: the viewing angle, the brightness of the reflection (bright reflection more opaque, darker reflection more transparent) and the brightness of the background (brighter background better visible, darker background less visible).
Now for an example in Blender: to the left is a wall with a bright pattern, to the right a wall with a dark pattern. Next to them on both sides are glass panes which the camera views both under a low angle. With a dark pattern on the background wall, both reflections are very good visible, the bright one almost completely hiding the background behind the glass:

If I now change the background to a bright pattern, it becomes much better visible through the glass, with the dark reflection becoming hardly visible and the pattern even being visible through the bright reflection:

Long story short: if you want to make a realistic render (and the scene looks like it is supposed to be realistic), I would actually keep it like it is.
But if you want to reduce the reflectivity, decreasing the IOR value will not have much of an effect, since the reflectivity will always be quite visible there unless the IOR is 1, and then the glass is simply invisible, transmission with IOR 1 is basically alpha transparent.
The only thing you could do is use the Fresnel or Facing output of a Layer Weight node, plug it into a Color Ramp to invert it and then plug it into the Alpha input of the Principled BSDF and play with the values until you like the result. However, in my opinion this will not look like real glass:



I've been experimenting with different approaches to the glass shader. Thank you, Gordon Brinkmann, for your detailed reply; inspired by your tip to use Fresnel as an input, I created this setup:

Mixing the Principled BSDF with a Refraction BSDF shader based on Fresnel resulted in this:

This seemed to improve the visibility of the tiles behind the glass panel. However, the reflections of the brighter tiles were still too visible, so I adjusted the shader again to this:

Now I'm using the Is Diffuse Ray from the Light Path node combined with an Add math node to determine how much of the diffuse color of objects behind the glass panels is visible, resulting in this slight difference:

Of course, this completely breaks realism, and when viewed from nearly perpendicular angles, the Refraction BSDF starts causing issues, like this weird black circle on the glass:

But if the image is never rendered from this angle, it should be alright. I thought I'd share this, as it might be useful to you or someone else.

Glad I could help and you found some solution. I actually only use a Principled BSDF or Glass BSDF 99% of the times I need a glass material. No mixing by light paths or anything else. And an additional Principled Volume for coloring sometimes.
